# The tkinter combobox does not work well with sqlite3 database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3-python

This is the simple code I want to execute. I want the elements of tkinter combobox come from sqlite3 database it does the job but It appends the first row and first column values many times(no of rows in database) . I want it to append the first column of each rows of databse.

```
con_caster = sqlite3.connect('caster.db')
con_sec = sqlite3.connect('section.db')
cur_caster = con_caster.cursor()
con_sec = con_sec.cursor()
#cur_caster.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS autos;")  # use this line only if you want to overwrite existing table
cur_caster.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS caster ('casterid' TEXT, 'casterradius' NUMBER);")
cur_caster = con_caster.cursor()
query = cur_caster.execute('SELECT casterid FROM caster')
caster_data = []
for row in cur_caster.fetchall():
    caster_data.append(row[0])
combo['values'] = caster_data
con_caster.commit()
```

And this is how I have created the rows in database

```
def add_to_database():
    i=0
    # add details to database
    caster_data.append((add_cid.get()))
    cur_caster.execute("INSERT INTO caster VALUES (?, ?);", (caster_data[i],caster_data[i] ))
    con_caster.commit()
    combo['values'] = caster_data
    i+=1
```

When I delete the database file and run the app it shows
[image: picture showing no data]
When I add data, the combobox looks like
[image: after addition of data]
After closing and opening app again he combobox looks like
[image: the second combobox elemant is replaced by first]
And the database also changes same as tyhe combobox.

Looking for the help in this.
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: There are utilities to look at the contents of an Sqlite database. You should use such a tool to check if the table contains the right data.

Comment: What is the output of `print(caster_data)` after the for loop?

Comment: @acw1668 it shows ```['e23e', 'e23e', 'e23e', 'e23e']``` which has repeated element from the database which has "e23e" as the first row and first column element . There must be some issue wih the for loop

Comment: It means that the table `caster` has 4 rows with same `casterid`. Since the column `casterid` is not a primary key, it can have duplicate value.

Comment: As the first comment said, you need to check the contents of the table using any sqlite tool.

Comment: @acw1668 I have checked And I came to know that there is problem with data. when I add the rows the dupluicate of first gets added to the database but the combobox works well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally removed the bug, There was problem with the data addition method.
Every time I needed to add data ro database I used to add the first element instead of entry value which was `caster_data[i]`
The correct snippet is.

```
  def add_to_database():
      i=0
       
      caster_data.append((add_cid.get()))
      cur_caster.execute("INSERT INTO caster VALUES (?, ?);", (add_cid.get(),add_cr.get() ))
      con_caster.commit()
      combo['values'] = caster_data
      i+=1
```

Comment: Why do you still keep the `i` variable?